# How to decrease the width of HDividedBox divider bar length in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

how we can lessen the length of Dividing bar between two components. like in this example i want the length only of two pixel.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the divider **thickness**!? In this case you have to adjust the values for the [DividedBox styles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/DividedBox.html#top) `horizontalGap` and `dividerThickness`. You should also consider `dividerAffordance`.